# Block or Prevent Temporary Email Address Domains

Tags: jquery, regex

I am new to jQuery and regular expressions and was wondering what would be the best way to add additional temporary email domains to this function from designchemical.com?

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#submit').click(function() {  

            $(".error").remove();
            var hasError = false;
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            var emailblockReg =  /^([\w-\.]+@(?!mailinator.com)(?!guerrillamail.com)(?!mytrashmail.com)(?!mailexpire.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

            var emailaddressVal = $("#Email").val();
            if(emailaddressVal == '') {
                $("#Email").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email!</span>');
                hasError = true;
            } else if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {    
                $("#Email").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email!</span>');
                hasError = true;
            } else if(!emailblockReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {   
                $("#Email").after('<span class="error">No Disposable E-Mail Address!</span>');
                hasError = true;
            } 

            if(hasError == true) { return false; }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Build `emailblockReg` using `new RegExp()` where you can use string manipulation to create your regexp from an array of strings.

Comment: it's worth saying, of course, that any blocking done on the client side can easily be bypassed by a user, and thus will need to be done as well on the server. Particularly if the aim is to prevent bots signing up to your site, you mustn't rely on the javascript code, as bots will often bypass it completely.

Answer (score 2):

First I'll preface this by saying you should always do your validation on the backend. But if you still want to use jQuery (for initial screening, etc), here's how I would do it:

Add another group to the email regex:

```
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}))?$/;
```

Create or pass in an array of unwanted domains:

```
var bad_domains = ['comcast.net', 'gmail.com'];
```

Check domain against each `bad_domain`:

```
var emailMatch = emailAddressVal.match(emailRex)
    domain = emailMatch[3];
for (var i = 0; i < bad_domains.length; i += 1) {
    if (domain.toLowerCase() == bad_domains[i])
        return false;
}
```

To add some custom action, just replace the `return false` with that custom action.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to do your validation on the backend since JavaScript can be intercepted and manipulated on the client side. Also throwaway emails appear everyday and if you don't want to keep your list updated on a daily basis you can simply use a third party API.

For example you can use my API [antideo.com](http://antideo.com/documentation/)

Here is a PHP example:

```
$request = file_get_contents('http://api.antideo.com/email/u978293@mvrht.net');
$response = gzdecode($request);
$result = json_decode($response);

if($result['disposable']) {
    echo 'Email is disposable'; 
} else {
    // email is not disposable do you stuff here
    echo 'Email is not disposable'; 
}
```

And JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.antideo.com/email/u978293@mvrht.net',function(result){
   if(result['disposable']) {
      console.log('Email is disposable');   
   } else {
      // email is not disposable do you stuff here
      console.log('Email is not disposable');
   }
})
```

Comment: I used CURL so that I could include the API Token.  Needed to use gzdecode() to extract the response.