# How to block entering gmail adress in textbox or show popup?

Tags: html, angularjs, regex

I need a `textbox` in my form for entering email address.But address should be business email.Never allow to enter personal `gmail` or `yahoo` address or show warning popup while doing so.How to implement that?Can i use `angulars` `ng-pattern` to implement it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371506/block-or-prevent-temporary-email-address-domains

Comment: Have you tried anything out?Something we can see?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. No need for angular pattern.

**HTML**

```
<form id="signup" method="post">
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your e-mail." />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#email').blur(function() {
    validateEmail($('input').val());
    return false;
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        if (email.indexOf('@yourdomain.com', email.length - '@yourdomain.com'.length) !== -1) {
            alert('Valid email.');
        } else {
            alert('Email must be a yourdomain e-mail address (your.name@yourdomain.com).');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Not a valid e-mail address.');
    }
}
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkuXC/909/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175111/validate-accept-only-emails-from-a-specific-domain-name/12175207#12175207)