# unable to regex certain pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression with the following requirements:
(1) not allow # 
(2) not allow & 
(3) not allow \t (tab) 
(3) not allow multiple spaces (single space is ok)

Here is I tried:

```
^[^#&\t\s+]*$
```

However, I can't get my output as I want. What am I doing wrong? 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have some examples as well? In which language are you trying this?

Comment: I'm guessing based on your tag history that this is in PHP or JavaScript? Different languages have different flavors (versions) of regex, so that is important to the question.

Comment: Your regex works fine on [www.regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kT1oK0/1).

Comment: When you say "single space is ok" does that refer to one space in the entire string, or to only having non-spaces adjacent to every space?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018848/how-to-block-entering-gmail-adress-in-textbox-or-show-popup

Comment: It's easier to construct a regex that *matches* the forbidden conditions, and reject it when it matches

Answer (score 0):

This will work in many regex flavors (including PCRE and JavaScript):

```
^(?!.*  )[^#&\t]*$
```

First, do a negative look-ahead to make sure there aren't any double spaces, and then match zero or more characters that aren't `#`, `&`, or `\t`.

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/uV1nP6/2)

Answer (score 0):

Break the task up into a basic expression for characters that *are* allowed, plus a negative look ahead anchored to start for the "no double spaces" assertion:

```
^(?!.*  )[^#&\t]*$
```