# unable to regex certain pattern (part 2)

Tags: php, regex

Cont from [unable to regex certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267507/unable-to-regex-certain-pattern)

I have the following regular expression:

```
^(?!.*  )[^#+&\'\"\\\\]*$
```

Now I want to fulfill the followings:

```
""      ---> invalid
" "     ---> invalid
" a"    ---> invalid
"a b"   ---> valid
"a  b"  ---> invalid
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: you want a regex that contains just one space, and not the excluded char you gave, right?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub yes...

Comment: Is a finishing space valid? Is it allowed to have multiple spaces in a string like `a b c`?

Comment: I think you need [`^[^#+&'"\\\s]+(?:\s[^#+&'"\\\s]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/gB4bY6/1)

Comment: @SebastianProske finishing space invalid...for the second part, yes, it allowed... but no double spaces between a and b or b and c ...

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!^.*\s{2}.*$)[^\s][^#+&'"\\\n\r]*[^\s]$
```

In php:

```
$re = "/^(?!^.*\\s{2}.*$)[^\\s][^#+&'\"\\\\\\n\\r]*[^\\s]$/m";
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dW3dC9/4)

---

`(?!^.*\s{2}.*$)` will ensure that the string doesn't contains consecutive spaces.

`^[^\\s][^#+&'\"\\\\\\n\\r]*[^\\s]$` will ensure that the string doesn't contain leading nor trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^[^#+&'"\\\s]+(?:\s[^#+&'"\\\s]+)*$
```

PHP:

```
$re = '~^[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+(?:\s[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+)*$~';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB4bY6/1). This regex does not allow consequent whitespaces and any leading/trailing whitespaces, is linear and fast.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^#+&'"\\\s]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and any of `#`, `+`, `&`, `'`, `"`, `\` chars
- `(?:\s[^#+&'"\\\s]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\s` - whitespace (1 time)
  - `[^#+&'"\\\s]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and any of `#`, `+`, `&`, `'`, `"`, `\` chars
- `$` - end of string (replace with `\z` for safer matching)

Here is an [IDEONE PHP demo](https://ideone.com/SEzCM2) that only echos `Matched 'a b'`:

```
if (preg_match('~^[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+(?:\s[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+)*$~', "")) {
    echo "Matched ''\n";
}
if (preg_match('~^[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+(?:\s[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+)*$~', " ")) {
    echo "Matched ' '\n";
}
if (preg_match('~^[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+(?:\s[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+)*$~', " a")) {
    echo "Matched ' a'\n";
}
if (preg_match('~^[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+(?:\s[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+)*$~', "a b")) {
    echo "Matched 'a b'\n";
}
if (preg_match('~^[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+(?:\s[^\s#+&\'"\\\\]+)*$~', "a  b")) {
    echo "Matched 'a  b'\n";
}
```